# google maps on iPhone

Tags: google-maps

I used google maps api v3 to add a map to website.  I turned off all the features and did an overlay of the united states.  I turned off everything so that it can be zoomed in or panned.  It works exactly how we want on the website, but when using  and iPhone it can't be scrolled.  How do I make it so that it is scrollable on an iPhone.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe on the iPhone you need to use two fingers to scroll in things like iFrames, or divs with overflow:hidden.  Maybe it's the same with your map.